# Identify a cartoon with a "red eyed tornado"

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Ok, so, I really really do not recall much about this, but I am sure that, as a kid (early '90), I watched more than once this cartoon, where there was a bad guy (... gal, maybe?) with magical powers, and at some moment s/he would transform in a big tornado with red glaring eyes.

My gut tells me that this could be Duck Tales and the bad one would be Amelia, but I tried googling around and found nothing, could you help me find out which cartoon was it?

EDIT: I remember the scene like this: after the transformation, there is a close view of the upper part of the tornado, which looks almost normal, until suddenly its red eyes open.

Comment: This sounds so familiar! I hope we get an answer.

Comment: Hm. Home Sweet Homer is an episode of Ducktales which has Circe from the Odyssey summoning a Time Vortex (tornado) a couple of times amount other spells, but she doesn't transform into one. Possibly a Magica de Spell episode? The Unbreakable Bin she is caught up by her own spell tornado.

Comment: Possibly Magica's Shadow War? Towards the end the shadows sneak around with glowing red eyes.

Comment: It was a tornado, not a simple shadow, and it had red eyes

Comment: You're sure you're not thinking of the Tasmanian Devil?  Technically he plays the bad guy in many cartoons, although not very magical

Comment: Pretty sure yes. Although I know he moves like a tornado, the one I remember was really big, not his size, and made of actual wind.